# How to create Kubernetes service with kubectl which exposes two ports

Tags: kubernetes

I have deployed a jenkins in Kubernetes. Now I want to create a service above the replicaset:

```
kubectl expose rs jenkins-xxx   --port=8080 --target-port=8080 --name=jenkins --namespace=ci
```

This works fine. `service-ip:8080` is redirecting to `pod:8080`. But I want also exposing `5000` inside the same service so that the service-ip is the same? How will my kubectl command look like? I want to do this with kubectl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `Pod` exposes multiple ports, you can use `kubectl expose` without any `--port` or `--target-port` parameters to expose them all as specified (e.g. 8080->8080 and 5000->5000).

```
kubectl expose rs jenkins-xxx --name=jenkins --namespace=ci
```

If you have more than those 2 ports specified on the Pod and only want to expose those 2, then you can't use `kubectl expose` and you'll have to create the `Service` manifest and `kubectl apply` it.

Comment: or `kubectl edit` the Service that was created by the "expose" command, which can, under certain circumstances, be a ton less typing

Answer (score 0):

put this yaml declaration in a file "your-service.yaml"

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: your-app
  name: your-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerSourceRanges:
  - 10.0.0.8/32
  ports:
    - name: some-endpoint-name
      nodePort: 30100
      port: 8081
      targetPort: 8081
    - name: another-endpoint-name
      nodePort: 30101
      port: 8082
      targetPort: 8082
  selector:
    app: your-app
```

run this from the same folder:

```
kubectl create -f your-service.yaml
```