# How to expose two apps/services over unique ports with k3d?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, traefik, k3s, k3d

**Cross-posted from k3d GitHub Discussion: https://github.com/rancher/k3d/discussions/690*

I am attempting to expose two services over two ports. As an alternative, I'd also love to know how to expose them over the same port and use different routes. I've attempted a few articles and a lot of configurations. Let me know where I'm going wrong with the networking of k3d + k3s / kubernetes + traefik (+ klipper?)...

I posted an example:
https://github.com/ericis/k3d-networking

#### The goal:

- Reach "app-1" on host over port 8080
- Reach "app-2" on host over port 8091

#### Steps

**See: [files in repo](https://github.com/ericis/k3d-networking)*

1. Configure `k3d` cluster and expose app ports to load balancer

   ```
   ports:
     # map localhost to loadbalancer
     - port: 8080:80
       nodeFilters:
         - loadbalancer
     # map localhost to loadbalancer
     - port: 8091:80
       nodeFilters:
         - loadbalancer
   ```
2. Deploy apps with "deployment.yaml" in Kubernetes and expose container ports

   ```
   ports:
     - containerPort: 80
   ```
3. Expose services within kubernetes. Here, I've tried two methods.

   - Using CLI

     ```
     $ kubectl create service clusterip app-1 --tcp=8080:80
     $ kubectl create service clusterip app-2 --tcp=8091:80
     ```
   - Using "service.yaml"

     ```
     spec:
       ports:
       - protocol: TCP
         # expose internally
         port: 8080
         # map to app
         targetPort: 80
       selector:
         run: app-1
     ```
4. Expose the services outside of kubernetes using "ingress.yaml"

   ```
   backend:
     service:
       name: app-1
       port:
         # expose from kubernetes
         number: 8080
   ```

Comment: I've read many posts about how to expose two ports with Kubernetes, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45621474/how-to-create-kubernetes-service-with-kubectl-which-exposes-two-ports. However, I get confused about how `k3d` is managing ports when the cluster is created and what exactly it does with kubernetes (k3s), klipper, and traefik.

Comment: your all files looking perfect however question using Loadbalancer work in K3D ? We only get the external IP while using the Cloud providers with local system like minikube and K3d we don't get the LB IP. also installed any ingress controller ?

Comment: Yes, k3d automates k3s, which comes with Traefik ingress controller and I believe the klipper load balancer

Comment: What is the actual issue here? If you want to expose services on different ports, you can use `type: NodePort` for your services. Your services will expose pods' ports to a free port on the node. And it will work. As for ingress, you have two rules, both point to `/` and it won't work this way. Please get familiar with [my answer about ingress and simple examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68449554/ingress-rule-using-host/68460360#68460360). Also fresh k3s has `traefik v2` which uses its own `api`.

Answer (score 4):

You either have to use an ingress, or have to open ports on each individual node (k3d runs on docker, so you have to expose the docker ports)

*Without opening a port *during the creation of the k3d cluster*, a nodeport service will not expose your app*

`k3d cluster create mycluster -p 8080:30080@agent[0]`

For example, this would open an "outside" port (on your localhost) 8080 and map it to 30080 on the node - then you can use a NodePort service to actually connect the traffic from that port to your app:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: some-service
spec:
 ports:
 - protocol: TCP
   port: 80
   targetPort: some-port
   nodePort: 30080
 selector:
   app: pgadmin
 type: NodePort
```

You can also open ports on the server node like:
`k3d cluster create mycluster -p 8080:30080@server[0]`

Your apps can get scheduled to run on whatever node, and if you force a pod to appear on a specific node (lets say you open a certain port on agent[0] and set up your .yaml files to work with that certain port), for some reason the local-path rancher storage-class just breaks and will not create a persistent volume for your claim. You kinda have to get lucky & have your pod get scheduled where you need it to. (if you find a way to schedule pods on specific nodes without the storage provisioner breaking, let me know)

You also can map a whole range of ports, like:
`k3d cluster create mycluster --servers 1 --agents 1 -p "30000-30100:30000-30100@server[0]"`
but be careful with the amount of ports you open, if you open too much, k3d will crash.

*Using a load balancer* - it's similar, you just have to open one port & map to to the load balancer.

`k3d cluster create my-cluster --port 8080:80@loadbalancer`

You then *have* to use an ingress, (or the traffic won't reach)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello
  annotations:
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: hello
            port:
              number: 80
```

I also think that ingress will only route http & https traffic, https should be done on the port `443`, supposedly you can map both port `80` and port `443`, but I haven't been able to get that to work (I think that certificates need to be set up as well).

Comment: I've had "0.0.0.0:8080->50001/tcp" for the loadbalancer. I've also created an ingress with port "number: 50001" to route to my k8s service at 50001. However, I can't acess it from host using 8080. It says "curl: (52) Empty reply from server". What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

### This is working just perfectly for me.

#### 3 quick steps and its sorted!

1. `k3d cluster create mycluster --registry-use registry  --servers 1 --agents 1 --port '3000:3000@loadbalancer' --port '8080:80@loadbalancer' --port '9443:433@loadbalancer' --port '8082:8082@loadbalancer' --port '8081:80@loadbalancer'`
2. `kubectl create service clsuterip.....targetPort`
3. `kubectl expose deploy my-app-deployment --name=my-app-deployment-lb --type=LoadBalancer`

background / explanation

i also had it working well and then I guess with version changes...it just stopped
but the setup is similar just one magical command fixed it, in the end.

On my ubuntu(VPS - nginx) : which just handles 80:433 (normal)
I just proxy (ssl wss whatever)

https://dev.domain.com:443 --> http://127.0.0.1:3000 or http://localhost:3000
any :port in the cluster I want to point to -  so i run:

```
k3d cluster create mycluster --registry-use registry  --servers 1 --agents 1 --port '3000:3000@loadbalancer' --port '8080:80@loadbalancer' --port '9443:433@loadbalancer' --port '8082:8082@loadbalancer' --port '8081:80@loadbalancer'
```

The command above sets up a typical cluster for me names myclsuter
The important part is 8080:80@loadbalancer (lowercase)

so after setting this it STILL WONT work , all we've done so far telling  the running k3d cluster that there **"might be"** or **"expect"**
a kubenetes loadbalancer waiting inside.
and with k3d you can also do setup commands pointing to @agent @server and all that ...but thats not useful to me.

so here I'm pointing 3000 to 3000 , 8080 to 80 and 9443 to 433  and so on (inside the cluster)

now...
create a ClusterIp svc for the deployment ...

```
kubectl create service clsuterip.....targetPort

kubectl expose deploy my-app-deployment --name=my-app-deployment-lb --type=LoadBalancer
```

thats it !
Your kubernetes deployment is exposed to the hosting machine on whatever port it uses.